# Outlook TableView items forecolor not updating

Tags: vba, outlook, properties

Im trying to create custom visualization (bold and forecolor proprerties) for outlook TableView for the inbox items.

Im able to update the the bold property from all inbox items, although it doesnt work for the color, extended color and underline. Also, how could i apply these properties for a single item instead of the whole view?

Why is that?

I have this testing VBA code:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim TV as TableView
    Set TV = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentView
    TV.RowFont.Size = 10
    TV.RowFont.Bold = False
    TV.RowFont.ExtendedColor = olColorFuchsia
    TV.RowFont.Color = olColorFuchsia
    TV.RowFont.Underline = True
    TV.Apply
End Sub
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.viewfont

Comment: @0m3r I've tried, no success...